# How to sign the Authentication?

Tags: c#, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am confused at how the AuthnResponseSignType works. When using the default, it is not being signed.

```
AuthnResponseSignType = Saml2AuthnResponseSignTypes.SignResponse
```

Signing both the response and the assertion does work.

```
AuthnResponseSignType = Saml2AuthnResponseSignTypes.SignAssertionAndResponse
```

Looking at the source, specifically https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/0c0cef05050d633f000be9399dc6a5b1a009a6da/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Bindings/Saml2PostBinding.cs#L37, it is a != when I think it should be an ==.

Thoughts? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The response is signed in [line 53](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/0c0cef05050d633f000be9399dc6a5b1a009a6da/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Bindings/Saml2PostBinding.cs#L53).

The `SignAuthnResponse` method should have been called something more meaningful, it only handles the assertion signing. The method has been [renamed](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/commit/7369eab07e96a4b8153e3a3c2dbae8f7b6c7de69).

Comment: But line 53 only runs if AuthnResponseSignType == Saml2AuthnResponseSignTypes.SignAssertion, not for SignResponse

Comment: If not, please se the ! --> if (!(saml2RequestResponse is Saml2AuthnResponse && saml2RequestResponse.Config.AuthnResponseSignType == Saml2AuthnResponseSignTypes.SignAssertion))